# Set scheduled email job programatically with Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've searched a lot of questions on Stackoverflow about using Heroku to send emails and schedule jobs and have come across these resources: [SendGrid](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sendgrid), [Heroku Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler). This looks fine but I'm still not sure if scheduling a job like this programatically is possible.

For example, in my Node.js app, I'd like a user to fill out a form with time intervals and choose components that would be sent with the email. This information would then be used to generate the scheduled email job.

**Is it possible to programatically schedule an email job from user input with Heroku?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku Scheduler is for configuring a small, fixed number of tasks. Kicking of dozens or more dynos dynamically (based on user input) could wreak havoc with your billing...

A separate worker dyno (acting in the role of cron) seems more suited for your use case - for example, translate the user input into a cron expression and then use a library like `later` (http://bunkat.github.io/later/index.html) to translate the expression into executable tasks. The task (which you write) then composes the message via whatever aggregation/composition requirements you have, then sends the email off via the transactional email provider of your choice (SendGrid is perfectly reasonable in that role).